# Can't write in global variable

Tags: javascript, function

Why i can't write in global varriable?

```
var postid=1;
request("get", {data:1}, function(data) {
alert(data.response[1].id); // get data
postid=2;
});
alert(postid); // get "1"
```

Comment: Please see [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your AJAX request is ***asynchronous*** and the alert is happening before the request completes and sets the `postid` value to 2.

Your order of events are likely:

1. Set postid = 1
2. Begin AJAX request.
3. Alert postid = 1.
4. AJAX request completes and sets postid = 2.

Comment: and what can i do with it? i use api and want to work with data i get

Comment: i use api and get it as is

Comment: @user3356784 Your comments aren't making much sense. It being an API is meaningless. It's ***your*** JS codes that needs to change. Either change your request to synchronous or add a callback method that fires inside your function when the request completes.